# get object data stdCLass in PHP

Tags: php, class

i want get data from stdclass object. i use foreach method to get key and value.
with var_dump i can get all infromation about the post, buy i want extract all 'display'.

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
                var_dump($value);
            }
```

var_dump result :

[image: var_dump result :]

i just want extract all display_ur property. can anyone exlain me ?

Comment: `var_dump($value->node->display_url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original array is made out of `stdClassObjects`. Each of these class objects has a public property called `node` that is also a `stdClassObject`.

That means that if you want to retrieve the display_url for each of these objects, you need:

```
foreach ($array as $object) {
   $node = $object->node;
   var_dump($node->display_url); // this should return what you are looking for
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Now i want to extract specific display_url. as yo can see data is array 0 to 5.
i want get one by one without var_dump. how can i do this ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have the display_url values to work with afterwards. You can replace the var_dump statement with something like $displayUrlList [] = $node->display_url; and initialize $displayUrlList = [] before the foreach statement. Afterwards you will get an array containing only the display_url values

Answer (score 2):

do like below:-

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $val){
        echo $val->node->display_url;
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Wilson  glad to help you. check my modified answer for your help

Answer (score 0):

$value->display_url. I think this will work for you.

Comment: Error : Undefined property: stdClass::$display_url

Comment: $value->node->display_url

Answer (score 0):

With type cast

```
 $array=(object) $stdClassObject;


foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                var_dump($value);
  }
```